An error when reading resources in release mode
My program contains two text files with some data as resources in visual C++. They can be load and read as follows.
const char* resQ = NULL, *resA = NULL;
GetTextResource(IDR_TEXT2, resQ);
GetTextResource(IDR_TEXT1, resA);

where the function GetTextResource() has the following definition:
void GetTextResource(int ID, const char*& data)
{
    HMODULE handle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC   hRes   = FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), L"TEXT");
    HGLOBAL rcData = LoadResource(handle, hRes);
    
    if (rcData)
    {
        DWORD   size   = SizeofResource(handle, hRes);
        cout << "Resource [" << ID << "] has been loaded successfully. Size of the resource = " 
             << size << " bytes\n";
    }
    data   = static_cast<const char*>(LockResource(rcData));
}

This method works pretty well in debug mode, but when I try to build a release version of the program it does not work at all. The program crashes with the message "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error..." .
It looks like the resQ and resA pointers are not getting resource data in release mode, or at least they are not getting the correct data. In both release and debug mode, the function GetTextResource() reports that the resources have been loaded successfully. I would like to know any ideas to fix this problem.
Thanks a lot for reading!

You need to check the return values for the function calls. Make sure they return proper valid values, and if not, use GetLastError

How do you create the . res file? Is it possible that the debug and release builds use different versions?

@500-internal-server-error I created a .res file with Visual C++. Thus, the versions of the debug and release resources should be the same.
I have just found out the cause of my problem. This is because the text in the resources does not end with a null character!  I do not know why there are differences in debugging and release modes, but if I set the null character manually, then both versions of the program work without errors.

So, thanks to your аdvices I was able to find the true cause of the error.
The problem is solved by adding a null character to the end of the resource string.
I have changed the function for resource loading like this.
char* GetTextResource(int ID)
{
    HMODULE handle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC   hRes   = FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), L"TEXT");
    if (!hRes)
        error("Resource not found!");
    HGLOBAL rcData = LoadResource(handle, hRes);
    if (!rcData)
        error("Resource not loaded!");
    
    DWORD   size   = SizeofResource(handle, hRes);
    cout << "Resource [" << ID << "] has been loaded successfully. Size of the resource = " 
         << size << " bytes\n";

    const char* data = static_cast<const char*>(LockResource(rcData));
    char *buff = new char[size + 1];

    memcpy(buff, data, size);
    buff[size] = '\0';
    return buff;
}

It turns out that in the debugging version of the program, the null character is automatically added to the end of the resource, but this does not happen in the release one.
